# Transpose Convolution feature extraction

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, convolution

Convolution extracts high-level features, but what about Transpose Convolution (or De/Up-Convolution)? Does it behave exactly the opposite? Does it generate lower-level features?

Comment: What is UpConv?

Comment: @user2974951 UpConvolution

Answer (score 0):

Upconvolutional layers are used to expand the spatial size of the input. So they do not "generate" features. It's just resizing itself. It does generates some numbers but  these numbers are the result of resizing itself. In the following example you might see the how Upsample works (in some cases it's called UpConv).

````py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

image = torch.tensor([[
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
], dtype=torch.float)

print("image size: ", image.size())
image = image.unsqueeze(0)
print("image size: ", image.size())
# image size:  torch.Size([1, 8, 8])
# image size:  torch.Size([1, 1, 8, 8])

downsample = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

downsampled_image = downsample(image)
print(downsampled_image)
''' Output
tensor([[[[0.0869, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312],
          [0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858]]]], grad_fn=<ConvolutionBackward0>)
'''

upsampled_image = upsample(downsampled_image)
print(upsampled_image)
'''
tensor([[[[0.0869, 0.0869, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312],
          [0.0869, 0.0869, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312, 0.3312],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858],
          [0.0636, 0.0636, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858, 0.3858]]]],
       grad_fn=<UpsampleNearest2DBackward1>)
'''

print(upsampled_image.size())
# torch.Size([1, 1, 8, 8])

```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what about transposed convolutions? I meant transposed convolutions in the answer (UpConvolution)